# Splitting a string into elements of a struct

Tags: c, string, struct, c-strings

I have a struct defined as below

```
struct gtid{
   int id1;
   int id2;
   int num;
 }
```

How can I convert a string in the form "1-2-3" and initialize the struct accordingly that is

```
  gtid -> id1 = 1;
  gtid -> id2 = 2;
  gtid -> num = 3;
```

Or How can I cast the string into the appropriate struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read formatted values from `stdin` with `scanf` function and from string with `sscanf` function. See the complete example below.

```
#include  <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int id1;
    int id2;
    int num;
} gtid_t;

int main(void) {
    gtid_t gtid;

    // read from stdin
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", &(gtid.id1), &(gtid.id2), &(gtid.num));
    printf("id1 = %d, id2 = %d, num = %d\n", gtid.id1, gtid.id2, gtid.num);

    // read from string
    char* str = "4-5-6";
    sscanf(str, "%d-%d-%d", &(gtid.id1), &(gtid.id2), &(gtid.num));
    printf("id1 = %d, id2 = %d, num = %d\n", gtid.id1, gtid.id2, gtid.num);

    return 0;
}
```

Output would be as follows

```
id1 = 1, id2 = 2, num = 3
id1 = 4, id2 = 5, num = 6
```

As @DavidC.Rankin mention in comments it is better to check that input was successful. You could add `if` statement like this one

```
if(sscanf(str, "%d-%d-%d", &(gtid.id1), &(gtid.id2), &(gtid.num)) != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input: %s\n", str);
}
```

As the result for `str` value `4-a-6` this example prints error

```
Invalid input: 4-a-6
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry but I don't want to read it from stdin. The string is already defined as a char *str. And first I need to check if the string is in  the correct format then convert it.

Comment: @RebeccaTucker my answer already has both examples with `stdin` and with string defined as `char*`.

Comment: Oh Thanks. That helps. please do you think it is necessary to check if the string has the correct format of x-y-z before converting? I would love to do that as well. I started learning how to code on Monday. Wish me luck !!

Comment: @RebeccaTucker Checking that the input data is valid is a good practice. Also welcome to StackOverflow! If the answer was helpful and solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks a million @nikolaykondratyev.  I definitely accept your response. It is exactly what I needed. Please could you do the check for me?

Comment: Yes, both are good examples, but in practice should be wrapped in `if (scanf (...) != 3) { handle error }` to validate each successful conversion. Both `scanf` and `sscanf` return a *match count* (which is the number of successful conversions that took place), so handling any error with both would be the same. Try your example with `"1-a-3"`...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @DavidC.Rankin. I have updated my answer.

Comment: So noted and voted. In your role as a teacher here on SO, it is good practice to help those your are helping understand how critical validating *all* input and *especially* user input is. Many times, you are the only person they are interacting with to get guidance on C, making sure you are passing on sound fundamentals (even if the fundamentals are slightly tangential to the exact problem goes a long way in helping fit the pieces of the puzzle together for them.