# How to pass a formatted string to a struct in C?

Tags: c

Referencing a similar question at [Splitting a string into elements of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670719/splitting-a-string-into-elements-of-a-struct).

In a part of my project, I have been entering into `signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)`. My task is to extract a formatted string from a file (which is a line of a file), and convert it into a struct. For example, I have already extracted a string "t,a,1990" and I would like to use `sscanf` to generate a struct `s` where `s.title` is "`t`" and so on. I noticed that in the struct given, title and artist are both pointers. I am new to the language and I am wondering why passing a pointer (`s.title` and `s.artist`) to a pointer is invalid here.

How can I solve it without changing the struct def?

Here is my code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char* title;
  char* artist;
  int year;
} song;

int main(void) {

    song s;

    // read from string

    char str[]= "t,a,1990";
    char* strptr = str;

    sscanf(strptr, "%s,%s,%d", s.title, s.artist, &(s.year));
    printf("title = %s, artist = %s, year= %d\n", s.title, s.artist, s.year);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is, that 'title' and 'artist' are simple pointers, that do not allocate any memory for you to write to.

Try `char title[20]; char artist[20];` and see if that gets you a little farther. :)

Comment: C doesn't have a string class. And that string class which C doesn't have is not `char*`. Therefore you need to manually ensure that enough memory for storing the symbols is available - it doesn't happen automatically. Basically you need to study arrays, then pointers, then strings in that order. Preferably by reading a good C book rather than crappy online tutorials.

Comment: @Lundin Aren't arrays technically pointers with different name/convention/expectation ?

Comment: @user426 No, arrays are arrays and pointers are pointers. An array identifier when used in most expressions "decay" into a pointer to its first element, but the array is still an array.

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you for the comment! I am taking an introductory coding program and I just noticed that they are actually two language!

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I am working on that. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @Lundin I am studying the language in a quite random order. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Each variable represents a specific amount of memory.
If you try to use more memory than you've allocated (reserved), segmentation faults happen.

In this case, you're 'reading a string to memory', without having allocated any memory to actually hold that memory. The pointer you are supplying does not actually point to anything.

As such, either:

- Allocate sufficient memory dynamically (and don't forget to clean up)
- Reserve sufficient memory during compile time.

For the latter case, your struct would look like this:

```
typedef struct {
  char title[20];
  char artist[20];
  int year;
} song;
```

This struct reserves 20 characters for your strings. As long as your strings are shorter than that, you're fine. If it gets longer, you'll run into the same problem as before.

Furthermore, the braces in `&(s.year)` are unnecessary. (`&s.year` is perfectly fine).

If you want to do it 'without changing the structure definition', you will need to work with dynamic memory allocation.

The key functions in C for this purpose are `malloc` and `free` (which require `stdlib.h`).
As such, your code would become:

```
char str[]= "t,a,y";
char* strptr = str;

s.title = malloc(20);
s.artist = malloc(20);

sscanf(strptr, "%s,%s,%d", s.title, s.artist, &s.year);
printf("title = %s, artist = %s, year= %d\n", s.title, s.artist, s.year);

free(s.title);
free(s.artist);
```

Failing to call 'free' leads to a memory leak.

Comment: Great answer, but I must point out that `malloc` and `free` are _not_ C keywords. They are functions provided in the standard library used after an `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: My apologies, that was poor phrasing on my part.

Comment: The next problem is likely due to your sscanf string. `%s` will read until the next whitespace character. Comma is not a whitespace character. If you only want to read until the next comma (and are sure that there are no commas in the payload), you may want to try `%[^,]` (Regular expression)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I appreciate the way you explain more than the code itself!

Comment: Eh, it's not a problem. As the old proverb goes: 'Give a man a fish and you'll feed him for one day.'
This site here isn't about handing out fish. It's about helping people learn fishing. :)
That said, if you consider your problem solved (or an answer useful), feel free to leave an upvote and mark one of the answers as 'accepted solution'. This way, others will know, that you no longer require aid in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

When you are making the variable `s`, `title` and `artist` have some garbage address from memory, when you are trying to fill them in the `sscanf` you are placing those strings to that address in memory *which you probably don't own*. You will need to set the address to memory space you own, for that you can either make 2 strings before, like this:

```c
int main(void) {
    char title[64];
    char artist[64];
    song s;
    
    s.title = title;
    s.artist = artist;
    /*...*/
```

but this isn't really a good looking code, for this purpose there is so called dynamic allocation... you can dynamically allocate memory at runtime with `malloc` function, that takes a size in bytes and returns address *(reference)* of the allocated memory:

```c
int main(void) {
    song s;
    
    s.title = malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
    //it's a good practice to check if system was even able to give us memory
    if(s.title == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    /*...*/

    //it's a good practice to free the memory when we are done with it
    free(s.title);
    free(s.artist);
```

But best way would be to allocate the whole structure at once:

```c
int main(void) {
    song* s;
    
    s = malloc(sizeof(song) + sizeof(char) * 128);
    if(!s)
        exit(-1);
    //since we are dealing with a pointer (reference) to the struct instead the struct itself, we need to use `->` operator to access the members...
    s->title = (char*)(s + 1);
    s->artist = s->title + 64;
    /*...*/
    sscanf("%s %s %d", s->title, s->artist, &s->year);
    /*...*/
    free(s);
```

Note that the sizes of those strings are limited so I suggest using `"%63s"` instead of `"%s"`...
**If you are using GCC compiler** and **you don't care about portability**, you don't have to do any of this *(well, except freeing the memory in the end)*, you can allocate the memory directly with the `sscanf` like this:

```c
sscanf("%ms %ms %d", s.title, s.artist, &s.year);
```

But with bigger projects I'd use some memory managment library, since malloc might have an impact on performance... Also to read comma separated values use `"%[^,]"` or better `%[0-9a-zA-Z ]`. *[This](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) is my go-to site for `scanf` documentation.*

Comment: Thank you WENDYN! Your explanation is really helpful! But when I try to allocate the whole structure as demonstrated in the third part, since `s` was initialized as a pointer, error occurs showing that `error: member reference type 'song *' is a pointer;`. It suggests to use `->` instead of `.`.

Comment: Mistake from my site, as it is a reference to the struct _instead of the struct itself_ you need to use `->` operator to access its members

Comment: "good practice to check if system was even able to give us memory" --> Yes, yet checking  return value of  ` sscanf()` is far more likely to detect an issue.  Best to check too.

Comment: You are right, I didn't bother including that in my answer since it wasn't on the topic of the question I think...